# How to color randomly drawn dots within a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to create the following plot (illustrating a population and a random sample) with tikz where the dots are created/placed randomly; all dots inside the circle, however, are supposed to be coloured in red:

[image]

Using answers based on previous (somewhat similar) questions, I was able to create the following plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {1,...,40}
    {
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{10}{390}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{10}{390}
      \fill (\a*0.01,\b*0.01) circle (0.1);
    };
    \draw (2,2) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I have no clue how to color the dots inside the circle in red (I have a vague idea that involves basic geometry and ifelse by checking every dot if it is placed inside the circle... does that make sense?).

Comment: a simpler way imho would be to draw some red dots inside a circle and some black ones outside, in two different loops... and maybe using polar coordinates would help!

Comment: What happens to the ones on the boundary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mathematically, a circle with radius `r` with center at `(a,b)` is defined by the equation

```
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2
```

So, to check if a point lies within this circle, you can check if the random points `(x,y)` satisfy

```
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= r^2
```

i.e. they are less than `r` away from the center of the circle. If you use `<=`, then points *on*  the border still count as "inside", if you use `<`, they won't.

To do that in Ti*k*Z, you can use the `ifthenelse` function provided by PGF Math. That is:

```
\pgfmathparse{ ifthenelse(condition, "value A", "value B")}
```

If the condition is satisfied, `\pgfmathresult` will contain `"value A"`, if not it will contain `"value B"`. We can use this to set the color either to  `"black"` or `"red"`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % Random seed for RNG
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

    % Define circle parameters
    \newcommand{\cX}{2}
    \newcommand{\cY}{2}
    \newcommand{\cR}{1}

    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- cycle;

    \foreach \x in {1,...,40}
    {
      % Find random numbers
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{10}{390}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{10}{390}

      % Scale numbers nicely
      \pgfmathparse{0.01*\a}\let\a\pgfmathresult
      \pgfmathparse{0.01*\b}\let\b\pgfmathresult

      % Check if numbers are inside circle
      \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse((\a-\cX)^2 + (\b-\cY)^2 <= \cR^2,%
          "red",
          "black")}
        \fill[\pgfmathresult] (\a,\b) circle (0.1);
    };
    \draw (\cX,\cY) circle (\cR);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 13):

If you don't mind working in points, then the TikZ `math` library may be helpful. Here, points are rejected if they would lie on the border of the circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\tikzmath{%
  coordinate \c, \p, \q;
  \q = (100, 100);
  \c = (30, 30);
  \R = 50;
  \r = 1;
  {
    \draw (-\qx, -\qy) rectangle (\qx, \qy);
    \draw [red] (\c) circle [radius=\R];
  };
  \x = \qx - \r; \y = \qy - \r;
  for \i in {0,...,100}{
    \p = (rand * \x, rand * \y);
    \v = veclen(\cx - \px, \cy - \py);
    if \v > (\R + \r) then {
      { \fill [black] (\p) circle [radius=\r]; };
    } else {
      if \v < (\R - \r) then {
        { \fill [red] (\p) circle [radius=\r]; };
      };
    };
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is one "clipping mask" solution:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
  % define clip mask with random points
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=rndpts]
    \fill[transparent!0] foreach ~ in {1,...,100}{(rand,rand) circle (0.02)};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
  % use it to clip rectangle and circle
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \fill[scope fading=rndpts, fit fading=true] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
      \fill[red] (2,2) circle (1cm);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[red] (2,2) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Metapost](http://tug.org/metapost.html) is also very good at this sort of diagram.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

numeric N, s, r;
N = 100; % population
s = 300; % size of square
r = 40; % radius of circle
z0 = (200,160); % center of circle;
color selected; selected = .73 red;

for i=1 upto N:
   z[i] = (uniformdeviate s, uniformdeviate s);
   drawdot z[i] withpen pencircle scaled 4 
     if r > length(z[i]-z0): withcolor selected fi;
endfor

draw fullcircle scaled 2r shifted z0 withcolor selected;
draw unitsquare scaled s;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's yet another solution that:

1. Sets the circle whose center defines the coordinate `center`, with a radius `\ra` (expressed in `pt`).
2. A `\foreach` loop that creates 200 random points, but you can change the number.
3. A measurement is done between `center` and each dot point.
4. Using an `\if` statement, if the length is above `50pt`, dots will be standard black, otherwise, they'll be colored red.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\ra{50}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,2) coordinate (center) circle (\ra pt);

\foreach \point in {1,...,200}{%
    \pgfmathparse{rand}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xdot{-7*\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{rand}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ydot{-5*\pgfmathresult}
%
    \coordinate (c\point) at (\xdot,\ydot);
    \tkzCalcLength(center,c\point) \tkzGetLength{myl}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\distance{\myl}
    \ifnum\distance>\ra
        \fill (c\point) circle (2pt);
    \else
        \fill[red] (c\point) circle (2pt);
    \fi
}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```