# draw random point in TikZ and create a contour with specific condition

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

[image]

Dear all,

I'm contacting you because I'd like to learn how to simulate this type of image with tikz.
I simulate points randomly (Poisson process, number of points 1024) in a rectangle ideally of size [31,31]. ([\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}])
Then i order the points increasingly  in a list (noted L) and draw groups of size 10.
For example
L=[x1,x2,x3,....,x_1024]
and then draw a contour on group [x_1,x_2,...,x_10]

1. step 1 order the point in a list,
2. generate a group of size 10 from the list and
   draw a contour.

For instance am trying to use the code from this link just to display the point.

[How to color randomly drawn dots within a circle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286755/how-to-color-randomly-drawn-dots-within-a-circle)

thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! "Draw a contour" sounds easy, but it is, in fact, not so easy to tell a computer *how* to draw a contour around things, at least not with a result as shown in your picture. Did you try something on your own already? It would help others help you if you could come up with some code to start with.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, this is not a "please do this for me" site. If there is a specific issue your are stuck on, such as how to plot random points in Ti*k*Z, you should refine your question. As it is, your question is too broad and will likely be closed until you can narrow its scope.

Comment: Am not telling you do this for me but if there is any idea or any link or any suggestion am open to and people aren't stupid if they want to help with any suggestion they'll do it.